# List comprehension with .append() produces [None] result

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm trying to write a code in Python 3.x using list comprehension. My code should print letters out of a list and remove duplication.

```
print(list(set(([letter_list.append(letter) for word in word_list for letter in word]))))
```

The code runs with no traceback errors but the output is `[None]`

Answer (score 1):

The `append` method modifies an (existing) list in place and returns None. A list comprehension creates a new list by itself, so you don't need appending here. Try this:

```py
print(list(set([letter for word in word_list for letter in word])))
```

Comment: You can also pass a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to the `set()` constructor